# Why doesn't index() working as expected

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div1">Div 1</div>
<div class="div2">Div 2</div> 
<div class="div3">Div 3</div> 
<div class="div4">Div 4</div> 

<div class="test">Test</div>
<br />
<div class="test">Test</div>
<br />
<div class="test">Test</div> 
<br />
<div class="test">Test</div>
<br />
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var i = $(this).index();
    alert(i);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9w5zS/)</kbd>

I would expect the result is `0, 1, 2, 3` but why the output is `4, 6, 8, 10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the output is `4, 6, 8, 10`

`$(this).index()` returns the index of the element relative to its **siblings**, not to the selected elements. The `br` and `.divX` elements are siblings as well!

It looks like you want:

```
var $tests = $(".test");

$tests.each(function(){
    var i = $tests.index(this);
    alert(i);
});
```

or simpler:

```
$(".test").each(function(i){
    alert(i);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy fix - .each supports index :

```
$(".test").each(function(idx){
    alert(idx);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

*index() gives index of element with respect to its siblings*. The first div with class text is 5th element and has index 4, br is at 5 index and next div with class test has index 6 and so on. We can check the indexes of each element by the following demo

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WqunB/)**

```
$("#parent1 *").each(function () {
    alert("TagName >> " + this.tagName + ", Index >> " + $(this).index() + ", Text " + $(this).text());
});
```

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is this:

```
$(".test").each(function(i) {
    alert(i);
});
```

[`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index) returns the index relative to its siblings.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make it relative to what you're testing against. Use:

```
$(".test").each(function(){
    var i = $('.test').index($(this));
    console.log(i);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9w5zS/1/)**

Per the docs on [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
>   jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.