# JQuery each(): index is always 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I've got a `jquery` .*each()* nested in a `Datatables` *action* function.  I'm trying to get the values(td) of the checked row, so I figured I use the index that's passed to the *each()* function and use the index to select the row(tr).  The index is always 0.  My approach seems flawed, but it's a start.  I need the values in the checked rows.

```
var data = hesTable.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (index, element) {
                        var item = $(this);
                        alert(index);
                        alert('Row index: ' + item.index())
                        alert('Row index: ' + item.parent().index());
});
```

HTML (MVC)

```
<tbody>
            @if (Model.HesViewModels != null)
            {
                // Can't use the DisplayTemplate here because need to assign Data-* attributes
                //
                //foreach (var item in Model.HesViewModels)
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.HesViewModels.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Make sure Hes Service returns data
                    //
                    if (Model.HesViewModels[i] != null)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => Model.HesViewModels[i].Process,
                                  new
                                  {                                      
                                      data_detailid = Model.HesViewModels[i].PartnerReferralDetailId,
                                      data_reasoncode = Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailReasonCode,
                                      data_statuscode = Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailStatusCode,
                                      data_outcomecode = Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailOutcomeCode
                                  })
                            </td>
                            <td>@Model.HesViewModels[i].PartnerReferralDetailId</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailStatusCode)</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailReasonCode)</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.HesViewModels[i].ReferralDetailOutcomeCode)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
```

RENDERED HTML

```
<input data-detailid="1578441" data-outcomecode="154" data-reasoncode="9" data-statuscode="8" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Process field is required." id="HesViewModels_0__Process" name="HesViewModels[0].Process" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="HesViewModels[0].Process" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Comment: You'll need to show your markup, but I imagine that you've got `input` elements in separate containers so that they're all the first child of their parent, i.e. `index = 0`.

Comment: I have a few _guesses_ about what your issue might be, but I can't tell because you have not provided an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: _"figured I use the index that's passed to the each()"_ `index` of `.each(function(index, element){})` not appear to be used ?

Comment: @guest271314...when I abbreviated the code I cut it out - it's back

Comment: @zzzzBov...I added HTML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853229/why-doesnt-index-working-as-expected

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum...that link is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try using selector `"table tr:has(:checked)"` to select only `tr` which have `input` element where `checked` is `true` . Approach iterates `tr` elements instead of `input` elements , to avoid need to select parent elements within `.each()`

```js
$("table tr:has(:checked)").each(function(index, element) {
  console.log($(this).index())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: @BigDaddy _"trying to get the values(td) of the checked row"_ Which values ? Can include rendered `html` at Question ?

Comment: I added rendered html

Comment: I'm working inside a Datatables table, so is your suggestion valid?

Comment: @BigDaddy _"working inside a Datatables table, so is your suggestion valid?"_ Should return expected results . Tried using `js`  at stacksnippets to check ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the index() is based on the siblings. Not all the checkboxes on the page. So use the index of the row.

```
item.closest("tr").index()
```

If you want to get the tds, than you really do not need the index()

```
item.closest("tr").find("td")
```

Comment: This assumes that there are no checkboxes in other table cells in this row. Heck, you don't even know he's even using tables.

Comment: It says TD in the question...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum OH look at that.... a table.

Comment: @epascarello...I'm getting the index with your code, but don't totally understand why.  Should I use the this index to get the rows values or is there a better approach?  Thanks

Comment: As I said index() gets the index relative to the siblings. Your checkbox sits in a TD so there are no siblings. If you want to get the tr the checkbox is in, use closest which climbs the parents until it matches the selector.

Comment: Oh wow you made a lucky guess to get quick reputation instead of educating the OP on how to write better questions by not answering incomplete questions. You must be proud. How silly I now feel.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum After being on the site for 7 years and catching hints, I understand how to answer poorly worded questions just like poorly worded requirements documents in my real job. It is not a lucky guess, it is an educated one based on ~3.9K answers If I would be wrong, I delete it.

Comment: Why did this answer get downvoted? It's (probably) the correct answer for this question and it works. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: @epascarello...I'd rather be lucky than good.  I don't understand the downvotes on your answer or my question either.  Sometimes the voting on SO baffles me.

Comment: @BigDaddy People get upset they miss clues. That is what happens. I am just here to help people and some people act like it is their job to police the site.

Comment: Down voting, in some cases, is ridiculous. I think SO should consider putting a limit on the dv at some percent of the user's uv. Otherwise, there seem to be trolls that look for any excuse to dv. (Further, without a requirement to comment on a dv, there's nothing to be learned from a dv.)

Comment: @Karl...You're right what can be learned?  How can I improve the question, which I and others would gladly do.  This should be about learning not policing and trolling.